# Bash script: Store awk field for later use

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I am writing a script which reads input from user and divides it into fields using `awk`. I wish to use one of those fields at the end of the script and hence am trying to store it in some variable but in vain.

One possible solution is to save the input and process it using `awk` again at the end, but I was wondering if there is any way to retain already processed info in some variable.

for example,

```
read -p "Enter args: "; echo -n $REPLY | awk '{ \*Do some stuff with fields*\; nth=$3}'

# More script

echo "Your 3rd argument was $nth"
```

but above doesn't work. `nth` is empty at end (which means it was local to `awk`?).

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about why you need awk, but you can add the `-a` flag to `read` so you get an array. Assuming the field/columns that you're talking about is delimited/separated by a space.

```
read -rp "Enter args: " -a input

printf 'Your 3rd argument was %s\n' "${input[2]}"
```

- Just remember bash arrays starts at zero index.

---

You can loop through the input.

```
read -rp "Enter args: " -a input

for ((i=0; i<${#input[@]}; i++)); do
  printf 'Your %d argument was %s\n' "$i" "${input[$i]}"
done
```

Or like this

```
read -rp "Enter args: " -a input

for i in "${!input[@]}"; do
  printf 'Your %d argument was %s\n' "$i" "${input[$i]}"
done
```

---

But here is what I would do using awk.

```
read -rp "Enter args: "

nth=$(awk '{\*Do some stuff with fields*\; print $3}' <<< "$REPLY")

printf 'Your 3rd argument was %s\n' "$nth"
```

---

Storing two fields, 2nd and 3rd in just one variable name.

```
read -rp "Enter args: "

nth=$(awk '{\*Do some stuff with fields*\; print $2, $3}' <<< "$REPLY")

printf 'The argument was %s\n' "$nth"
```

---

If you want to split the 2nd and 3rd field in a different variable name.

```
read -rp "Enter args: "

nth=$(awk '{\*Do some stuff with fields*\; print $2, $3}' <<< "$REPLY")

printf 'Your 2nd argument was %s\nYour 3rd argument was %s\n' "${nth#* }" "${nth% *}"
```

- The `"${nth#* }"` and `"${nth% *}"` can be saved with a separate variables.

---

One more answer to this `awk` printing all the fields using `$0` and `read` which comes back to my first answer using `read -ra`

```
read -rp "Enter args: "

read -ra fields  < <(awk '{\*Do some stuff with fields*\;print $0}' < <(printf '%s' "$REPLY"))
```

Print All the fields

```
printf '%s\n' "${fields[@]}"
```

- My first post/answer to this question shows how to loop throught the fields of bash arrays and how it is indexed as well.

Comment: Thanks! I'm being greedy but can we extend to more than 2 variables with the `"${nth#* }" and "${nth% *}"`

Comment: Use an array, like the last example, that way you can store and process all the colums/fields.